# Turbo Pascal: Replace character in String with other character

Tags: string, replace, char, str-replace, pascal

As its said in the title, im writing a really simple encoding and decoding program with turbo pascal for school and im having trouble finding a solution to replace certain characters in a string.

Thx for the help

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.* If you can't get started on your assignment, ask your instructor for help. If it's not homework, [edit] your question to include the code you've written so far that isn't working for you, and ask a specific question related to that code. We're not a code writing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is homework, I'm not going to give you code that does it, but rather explain **how** to do it using TP's string-processing facilities.  It's years since I had a working copy of TP installed, but from memory:

The key thing about a String in TP is that it can be declared with a maximum length of 255 and is effectively an array of these characters (numbered 1.. max) preceded by a "length" byte which indicates the current number of characters in the string.

So, if you have this declaration

```
var S : String[20];
```

you can do an assignment like this

```
S := 'Hello World';
```

and you can access the individual characters as

```
S[1]
```

whose value is 'H',

```
S[2]
```

which is 'e' etc.  Never assume anything about the characters beyond the current length of the string as returned by the Length() function.

So, to replace a substring in a string, one way is to

1. Find the position of the substring in the string.  You can use TP's Pos() function for this.
2. If Pos() finds the substring, it will return a positive integer, otherwise 0.  Let's call the return value P.
3. If P is greater than zero you can use TP's Delete() procedure to delete a specified number of characters from the string, starting at a specified position.  So, you would call Delete on your string, passing P as the starting position and Length(SubString) as the number of chars to delete.
4. Then you can use TP's Insert procedure to insert the replacement substring, starting at P, the position where the original substring was found.
5. The above steps are for replacing a substring of arbitrary length by another which may differ in length or even be empty (in which case, just omit the Insert() call.  In a situation where you want to do a one-for-one replacement of one single character in the string by another single one, you can do it by direct assignment, as in

   `S[2] := S[1];`

so S becomes 'HHllo World'

or

```
S[1] := 'A';
```

Comment: thx for helping out, i will try my best. also thx for not just giving me the code. i would rather learn it myself than just copy-pasting

Comment: That's a good attitude.  If you get stuck, just ask for a hint.

Comment: Martyn, since OP says 'replacing character with other character' in terms of en/decoding, maybe you could add a fifth point regarding direct assignment.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, well spotted, thanks.  I've added a point 5 about this.

Comment: @Nikolas:  Btw, if you get an answer which helps you, it's good to get into the habit of "accepting" it by clicking the green "tick" icon at the top left of the answer.  Doing this increases the questioner's and answerer's reputation a bit and also makes the Q & A a bit more prominent on SO and therefore maybe more likely to help future readers.

Comment: @Martyn, can you give me a hint on how to replace a Char in the string with a number?

Comment: @Nikolas:  Well, in strings, numbers (digits) are just characters too, just like letters.  Take a look at an ASCII chart like this one:http://www.asciitable.com/.  As you can see, "A" has the decimal ASCII code 65 and "4" the code 52.  You could write S[1] := '4' or use the TP Chr() function, as in S[1] := Chr(52)

Comment: @MartynA finally got the job done after 2hrs of hard work :D worth it

Comment: @Nikolas:  Good for you, well done!  It makes such a great change from people who turn up here on SO expecting others to do their thinking for them.  For your next q, make sure you have had a look at the help guidelines Ken White pointed you at in his comment.  You might be pleasantly surprised how ready people are to answer qs that show a bit of effort by the person asking.